# Junit testing for exceptions

Tags: exception, junit

What is my mistake in the Code below especially in 'testSetEmailString()'?

```
package de.hhn.pp.addressBook.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import de.hhn.pp.addressBook.logic.ContactImplementation;
import de.hhn.pp.addressbook.api.exceptions.StringNotValidException;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Asd {

private String email;

private boolean expectedValue;

private ContactImplementation contact;

public Asd(final String email, final boolean expectedValue) {
    this.email = email;
    this.expectedValue = expectedValue;
}

/**
 * Data.
 *
 * @return the collection
 */
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] {

            // INVALID EMAIL ADDRESSES
            // it is not allowed to have digits in the Top Level Domain
            { "personalproductivity@hotmail.com2", false },
            // it is not allowed to have the '@' twice
            { "personal@productivity@hotmail.de", false },
            // it is not allowed to have special character such as '!'
            { "personal!productivity!@hotmail.de", false },
            // Top Level Domain cannot start with a '.'
            { "personalproductivity@.gmail.com", false },
            // email address must contain a '@'
            { "personalproductivity.de", false },
            // email address must contain a Top Level Domain
            { "personalproductivity@", false },
            // it is not allowed to have double '.'
            { "personal..productivity@web.de", false },
            // it is not allowed to start with a '.'
            { ".personalproductivity@gmx.edu", false },

            // VALID EMAIL ADDRESSES
            { "personalproductivity@hotmail.de", true },
            { "personal+productivity@hotmail.com", true },
            { "personalproductivity2015@web.edu", true },
            { "personal.productivity-SS15@gmail.com", true } };
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}

@Test(expected = StringNotValidException.class)
public void testSetEmailString() {
    contact.setEmail(email);
}

@Test
public void testIsEmailPatternValid() {
    boolean result = ContactImplementation.isEmailPatternValid(email);
    assertEquals("Result", this.expectedValue, result);
}
```

}

In my implemented class, the first Method 'setEmail(String)' sets the new email address by checking if the static method 'isEmailPatternValid' returns true. If the email is invalid, a new Exception is thrown, StringNotValidException.

The isEmailPatternValid test works pretty. But I want to check also the setEmail Method for better code coverage. I have problems in Exception testing.

Comment: "I have problems", "What is my mistake" - what is the actual question? What is the problem, what is the error/console/debugger output?

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. Don't tell you have an exception. Post the exact and complete exception stack trace.